# HTML page designed with bootstrap occupies full height in Chrome,Firefox ,IE,Opera but not in Edge

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, meta

I have a HTML page with forms ad content that i built with bootstrap which occupies full width and height of Opera,IE,Firefox and Chrome but when i run it in Edge it only occupies like 75 % ,only when i set the zoom to 125% in edge it renders the same way as it did in other browsers . Is there like any meta tag 
like

```html
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
```

to make Edge use the same settings like IE?

I was using this meta tag ,right after the header tag

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

my html page:

```css
html {
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}

body {
    margin-top: 50px;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}

.fullwidth {
    width: 100%;
}

.halfwidth {
    width: 50%;
}

.fullscreen {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.halfscreen {
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
}

.verticalscrollbar {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Best Taxi</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/site.css" />
    <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
   <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="Images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="icon" href="Images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
</head>
<body class="background-plain">
    <div id="page">
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Best Taxi</a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="About.html">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="cityattractions.html">City Attractions</a></li>
                         <!--Code for drop down link ,sub menu-->
                         <!-- <li class="dropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Drop Down Link
        <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">The Museum</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">The Palace</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">The Zoo</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>-->
                        <li><a href="Tours.html">Tour Packages</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Rates.html">Pricing</a></li>
                        <li class="active"><a href="ContactUs.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!--/.nav-collapse -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <section id="Main" class="container col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 fullscreen">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 halfscreen">
                <div id="Address" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <h2>Address</h2>
                    <hr />
                    <div id="col-lg-6 col-md-6" style="float: left;">
                        <h5>Address:Flat Number 1,</h5>
                        <h5>Building Number 1000</h5>
                        <h5>EverGlade Street,</h5>
                        <h5>Way Number 15678,</h5>
                        <h5>DownTown,Thimphu</h5>
                        <h5>Bhutan</h5>
                        <h5>Phone:0000000000</h5>
                        <h5>Mail:info@besttaxi.com</h5>
                    </div>
                    <div id="AddressImage" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 visible-lg visible-md">
                        <img src="Images/taxi_mail.png" class="img-responsive" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="ContactUsForm" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <form>
                        <h2>Contact Us</h2>
                        <hr />
                        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                            <h5>Name:</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
                            <input id="ContactName" type="text" class="form-control" required />
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                            <h5>Email:</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
                            <input id="ContactEmail" type="text" class="form-control" required />
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                            <h5>Subject:</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
                            <input id="ContactSubject" type="text" class="form-control" required placeholder="joe@gmail.com" />
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                            <h5>Message:</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
                            <textarea rows="5" cols="70" class="form-control"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4"></div>
                        <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
                            <br />
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-yellow">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="AddressMap" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 halfscreen">
                <br />
                <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m12!1m3!1d3539.890031078142!2d89.6358250609653!3d27.47268275781882!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!5e0!3m2!1sen!2s!4v1485174584064" class="fullwidth" height="260"></iframe>
            </div>

            <hr />
        </section>

        <footer class="container navbar-fixed-bottom hidden-xs hidden-sm">
            <p class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">Copyrights © 2017 Best Taxi rights reserved | Developed by Nakki </p>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post some form of code or example to demonstrate this. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)